# print the content type name on the page tpl

Tags: php, drupal

The code below will exclude the content type 'name' from being printed on a Page and Story type. Question, how can I do the opposite of this and print the content type name on only a Page and Story type?

```
    <?php
    if (!in_array($node->type, array('story', 'page'))) {
    print node_get_types('name', $node);
    }
    ?>
```

I removed the (!) and it works. How can I embed a css style into this scprit. I get error when I tried it this way. I just need the style to show on Page or Story types.

```
    <?php
    if (in_array($node->type, array('story', 'page'))) {
    <div class="mystyle">
    print node_get_types('name', $node);
    </div>
    }
    ?>
```

I got the css style in using 'print'

```
    <?php
    if (in_array($node->type, array('story', 'page'))) {
    { print '<div class="mystyle"> ';
    print node_get_types('name', $node);
    }
    print '</div>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I found it..

        <?php
        if($node && in_array($node->type, array('story', 'page'))) 
        { print node_get_types('name', $node);}
        ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question correctly, just remove the not (!) operator, e.g:

```
<?php
if (in_array($node->type, array('story', 'page'))) {
     print node_get_types('name', $node);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `!` operator:

```
if (in_array($node->type, array('story', 'page'))) {
  print node_get_types('name', $node);
}
```

Comment: How can I embed a css style into this. I get errors when I do it this way.


        <?php
        if (in_array($node->type, array('congressionaltestimony', 'newsletter', 'event', 'factsheet', 'pressrelease', 'speech'))) {

<div class="mystyle">
 print node_get_types('name', $node);
</div>

}
?>